# How do I prompt the user to enter in either a character or a number?

Tags: c++

Lets say I'm making a math program simple arithmetic quizing program. It gives a random number and asks the user to enter in the answer as an integer or q to quit. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the answer as a string, then check if it is == "q", exit, else, convert it to an integer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    std::string got;
    std::cin >> got;
    if(got == "q")
            return 0;
    else {
            int i = std::atoi(got.c_str());
            std::cout << i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```